# Spring Injection isn't working in Jersey Filter - @InjectParam Equivalent in jersey2

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, jersey-2.0

I'm trying to inject an object in Jersey-Filter using spring injection.

If I try the **@Inject** method, then I'm ending up with an exception

```
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
MultiException stack 1 of 2
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find an active context for org.jvnet.hk2.spring.bridge.api.SpringScope
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl._resolveContext(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:2058)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.access$000(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:120)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl$2.compute(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:186)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl$2.compute(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:182)
```

If I try using **@InjectParam** that its defined in Jersey 1.x however I'm using Jersey 2.17 in which this annotation is not found.

Any idea how to perform this spring injection in jersey-filter?

What's does the exception mean?

`Could not find an active context for org.jvnet.hk2.spring.bridge.api.SpringScope`

Comment: It looks to me like at initialization time the spring bridge has not been properly initialized.  I'm not sure how this is done in Jersey, but you can see more about the spring/hk2 bridge here: https://hk2.java.net/2.5.0-b03/spring-bridge.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update Edit:**
Additionally you can provide a constructor injection. Jersey's constructor injection worked for me in Filter's rather than Field Injections

**Old :**

I implemented this by Injecting the **javax.servlet.ServletContext** inside the filter and using that to get the beanIds using **WebApplicationContextUtils**

```
public class LoginFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Context private HttpServletRequest servletRequest;

    @Context private HttpServletResponse servletResponse;

    @Context private ServletContext servletContext;

public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {

        try {

            WebApplicationContext springContext = 
                    WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(servletContext);

            CookieAuthenticator     cookieAuthenticator = springContext.getBean(CookieAuthenticator.class);

            LoginInterceptorHelper  loginInterceptorHelper = springContext.getBean(LoginInterceptorHelper.class);

            HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);

            UserSummary user = (UserSummary) session.getAttribute(WebConstants.USER_DETAIL);
```

And By including a spring listener so spring initialization happens first.

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

This works. 
But instead of injection I'm explicitly loading the dependencies.
Is there any better way to do this?